# Minikube Pods are not able to communicate with each other

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am running a minikube cluster locally.
I have a simple spring boot app trying to connect to a Mysql Pod deployed in the same namespace. Spring boot app is using 'spring-data-jpa'.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:30060/bootappdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Here are the kubernetes deployment yaml manifests.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql8
  namespace: bootapp
  labels:
    app: mysql8
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql8
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql8
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql8
          image: mysql:latest
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: "root_nimda"
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: bootappdb
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: admin
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              value: nimda
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
  namespace: bootapp
  labels:
    app: mysql8
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql8
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: mysql-server
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      nodePort: 30060
```

Boot app Yaml is :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory-service
  namespace: bootapp
  labels:
    app: inventory-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory-service
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
      containers:
        - name: inventory-service
          image: inventory-service:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "512m"
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "512m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8085
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: "mysql-service"
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "30060"
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: "k8s"
            
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 50%
      maxUnavailable: 20%
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 30
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 300
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventoryservice
  namespace: bootapp
  labels:
    app: inventory-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: inventory-service
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: inventoryservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8040
      targetPort: 8040
```

When I tried to check the network configured for docker containers created by minikube, surprisingly they all are connected to 'none' network. I was expecting them to be part of some 'bridge' network.

If all the containers are connected to 'None' network, then how would they be able to communicate with each other ?

Any pointers to investigate this further ?

Am i missing any configuration setting to let minikube setup a common network for all pods in the cluster ?

Spring Boot Application does not start with a SocketTimeoutException while configuring the DB connection pool.

Comment: Connections from a Pod to a Service use the Service's `port:`, so you should use the standard MySQL port 3306 in `$DB_PORT` and your connection string.  The `nodePort:` is only used for connections from outside your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by David, a service of type 'ClusterIP' is required to facilitate intra-cluster connectivity.

Following service manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-peer-service
  namespace: bootapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql8
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10800
  ports:
  - name: mysql-peer-service
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3309
    targetPort: 3306
```

And,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-peer-service:3309/bootappdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Works fine.